# Combinatorics: N^N unique objects with N options for N properties

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Say I have a collection of N^N objects. The objects have N properties, e.g. shape, size, color, material, etc. Also, for each of the N properties, there are N options, e.g. for shape there could be square, circle, triangle, hexagon, etc. If I have 1 of every unique object (e.g. 1 that is a small red metal triangle), this means I have N^N total objects.

My question is, how many ways can I make a set of N objects such that for every one of the N properties of the set of N objects, either:

1. the N objects have the exact same option for that property (e.g. for the color property, they all have the red option), or
2. every one of the N objects has a different option for the given property (e.g. for color, there is a red, blue, green, etc., all unique with

---

As a simple example, for N=3, things are easier because the first 2 objects of a set of N=3 objects uniquely determine what the 3rd object must be. But how can I generalize this to arbitrary N?

For the case of N=3, you can see the derivation here in this combinatorics book, problem 26, on book pg. 36 (pg. 49 of the pdf):
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5eLyVMIO4AwYmUyZmRkYzMtOTJkYy00MTM0LTg5OTAtNTQwOTBmNTBlODZl/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ be the number of properties in common. Then there are ${N \choose k}$ ways to pick the set of common properties. The first set element can be picked in $N^N$ ways. The second element must match on $k$ properties, and be different for the other $N-k$, leaving $(N-1)^{N-k}$ possibilities for the second set element. Then there are $(N-2)^{N-k}$ possibilities for the 3rd element, etc. Noting that each set gets counted $N!$ times, the total number of such sets is
$${N \choose k} N^k (N!)^{N-k-1}$$
Add these up as $k$ varies from 0 to $N-1$ to get the total.